# My code will not read my XML file

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2012

My code for saving data in XML Work just fine. but when i want to load it into DataGrid it can not find the file

here is my XML note:

```
<Bruger>
  <Leder ID="1">
    <Navn>awrea</Navn>
    <Efternavn>aerg</Efternavn>
    <Kva1>arwgllll</Kva1>
  </Leder>    
</Bruger>
```

And here is my not wokring code: it keeps saying cannot find the file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;

    private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                XmlDataDocument xmldata = new XmlDataDocument();
                xmldata.DataSet.ReadXml(Application.StartupPath + "@leder.xml");

                dataGridView1.DataSource = xmldata.DataSet;
                dataGridView1.DataMember = "Leder";
            }
```

Comment: Verify that `Application.StartupPath + "@leder.xml"` actually point to the file.

Comment: Maybe you misplaced the @ sign? Is the file called @leder.xml?

Comment: Please post the full path of Application.StartUpPath. Also post the full path of the XML file.

Answer (score 3):

Put Application.StartupPath + "@leder.xml" into a string and show the contents of it or simply debug it.

Also does your filename contain @?

Comment: my File name does not contain @

How would you suggest doing the string?

Comment: Please add the full path of the XML file.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you mean

```
xmldata.DataSet.ReadXml(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "leder.xml"));
```

it's likely that `@` stuck around from when you had a hardcoded path during debugging.

You also need to use `Path.Combine` to ensure that the path is built with the appropriate `\`.